# Clojure way of for...in

Tags: clojure, hashmap, iteration

What is the clojure way of for...in ?
Say I am doing some job like(maybe)

```
for key in map.keys do
    FUNC(key)
end
```

to construct a new map, using key of map as new map's key, and some return values as new map's value.

Comment: The text in your edit is a completely new, unrelated question. Please ask that in a new question, rather than by editing it into this one.

Comment: Ok thanks for reminding